# Mongodb $and and $sort on different fields and getting last matching record

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection with around 50 lake records.Below is one sample document

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(4253223),
    "locId" : 59,
    "startIpNum" : NumberLong("3287940726"),
    "endIpNum" : NumberLong("3287940761"),
    "maxmind_location" : {
        "locId" : 59,
        "country" : "DK",
        "region" : "",
        "city" : "",
        "postalCode" : "",
        "latitude" : "56.0000",
        "longitude" : "10.0000",
        "metroCode" : "",
        "areaCode" : "\n"
    }
}
```

Below is Query I am trying to perform.I want to find last record from the matching condition.

```
find({
        $and: [
                 {startIpNum: { $lte: 459950297 }},
                 {endIpNum: { $gte: 459950297 }} 
              ]
      }).sort({_id : -1}).limit(1)
```

I have septate  ascending index on  `startIpNum` and `endIpNum`. I have replaced `_id` with incremental id value like Mysql.

When I do query without `sort` and with `limit 1`. It gives me result in 0ms. As soon as I put `sort` (I need sort since I want last matching record ) the query get hang forever.

I have also tried below query, but It takes around 700ms. With compound
index on `{startIpNum :1 , endIpNum : 1 , _id : -1 }` with the sort on `_id`.

```
 find({
         startIpNum : { $lte: 459950297 }, 
         endIpNum : { $gte: 459950297 }
      }).sort({
                 startIpNum :1,
                 endIpNum :1 ,
                 _id : -1
              }).limit(1).explain({ verbose : true});
```

How can I achieve sort in my first approach.

Here is explain. Its still scanning 370061 indexes for

```
db.maxmind.find({startIpNum : { $lte: 459950297 }, endIpNum : { $gte: 459950297 } }).sort({startIpNum :1, endIpNum :1 , _id : -1 }).limit(1).hint("startIpNum_1_endIpNum_1__id_-1").explain( { verbose: true } );
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "yogeshTest.maxmind",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "startIpNum" : {
                        "$lte" : 459950297
                    }
                },
                {
                    "endIpNum" : {
                        "$gte" : 459950297
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "startIpNum" : 1,
                        "endIpNum" : 1,
                        "_id" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "startIpNum_1_endIpNum_1__id_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "startIpNum" : [
                            "[-inf.0, 459950297.0]"
                        ],
                        "endIpNum" : [
                            "[459950297.0, inf.0]"
                        ],
                        "_id" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 433,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 370061,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 430,
            "works" : 370062,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 370060,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 2891,
            "restoreState" : 2891,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "limitAmount" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 420,
                "works" : 370061,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 370060,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 2891,
                "restoreState" : 2891,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 410,
                    "works" : 370061,
                    "advanced" : 1,
                    "needTime" : 370060,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 2891,
                    "restoreState" : 2891,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "startIpNum" : 1,
                        "endIpNum" : 1,
                        "_id" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "startIpNum_1_endIpNum_1__id_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "startIpNum" : [
                            "[-inf.0, 459950297.0]"
                        ],
                        "endIpNum" : [
                            "[459950297.0, inf.0]"
                        ],
                        "_id" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 370061,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "cus360-H81M-S",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.0.3",
        "gitVersion" : "b40106b36eecd1b4407eb1ad1af6bc60593c6105"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: You already have an index on just _id also, right?

Comment: yes I have index on _id as well.

Comment: can you also post the result of `db.collection.getIndexes()`?

Comment: as well as the output of your query `explain`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you post the output for `db.collection.getIndexes()` and `explain` of your query, let us try the following. What I suspect is that your `{startIpNum :1 , endIpNum : 1 , _id : -1 }` does not win as a query plan.

So what you can try is force MongoDB to use that index by hinting:

```
find({
         startIpNum : { $lte: 459950297 }, 
         endIpNum : { $gte: 459950297 }
      }).sort({
                 startIpNum :1,
                 endIpNum :1 ,
                 _id : -1
              }).limit(1).hint({startIpNum :1 , endIpNum : 1 , _id : -1 })
```

Currently it seems like your query fetches all the matching documents, loads them into memory, and sorts them there. With hinting, using your index, it will just pick your documents in the right order initially.

Comment: can u pls check the explain. It has reduce to around 450 ms but scanned 3700061 indexes.

Comment: is 370061 the number of your documents? Please notice that `"totalDocsExamined" : 1`, which means that the query is able to make comparisons only by the index, and does not need to examine the whole document. The only document examined is the one that was returned.